# Hot reloading anonymous functions in a custom scripting language

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, language-features

I am implementing anonymous functions (lambdas) in a scripting language that supports hot reloading. The language currently supports passing user defined functions (pointers) to plugin functions which can store the function pointers to be called later  (event handlers). With lambda support I can dynamically create the functions from the compiled bytecode when it is parsed and then that pointer gets passed to the plugin function and stored. The problem is with the hot reload functionality, I need to be able to update the bytecode that the function pointers stored in the plugins point to. This is hard since there is no way to know if the new bytecode still contains that lambda or if it's meant to be replaced by a different lambda. Furthermore if a lambda is removed then the plugin is storing a pointer to a removed function.

The only (half) solution I have come up with is forcing the programmer to give the function a name, which then can be looked up and the bytecode replaced. But then it's not really an anonymous function anymore.

I realise this is a nasty problem, and I fully expect the answer to be "it's not possible". But I'd like to ask to see if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: Don't you have the exact same problem with non-anonymous functions? I mean, if  calls , and  is removed during the hot reloading while  is executing, then eventually the application will crash.

Comment: In that case I could waste memory keeping the removed function that the pointer points to stored in heap, but blacklist it from execution the next time.

Comment: Are you sure you want to update the code inside the lambda? Oftentimes you use lambdas to include scoped data that is only available when you create the lambda - when you hot-reload your code that creation code has to run again. Wouldn't it be sufficient to just store and pass a (smart) pointer and only update references to global state in the lambdas body on reload? Of course the code that has been passed once would never change, but as a user I probably wouldn't expect it to.

Comment: Good point, I decided to just invalidate the function instead and tell users to reregister the functions if they hot reload. The other option is a can of worms.

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution is to cheat: anonymous function may actually have a name, although the name would be hidden from a programmer.

Since you need to keep track of the code changes, i.e. know whether an anonymous function was removed or simply altered, I would suggest using a deterministic name, such as a hash based on the signature of the function, and its closure, that is, the variables from the upper stack, used inside the function itself.

- If such function gets removed (or changes its signature or is moved to a different location), the new code won't have a function with the same hash. You will then treat this case identically to the case where a named function gets removed, i.e.  calls , and  is removed during the hot reloading while  is executing.
- If such function changes its body, the situation is by no means different from the one where a named function changes.

Comment: That's e.g. how lambdas were added to C# and anonymous classes were added to Java without needing additional support in the VM. E.g. Anonymous classes in Java are compiled to regular classes in the JVM with names that are illegal in Java but not in the JVM.